# OpenGL include statements

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, glut

I'm attempting to work with openGL in visual studio 2010, and so far my code looks like so

```
#include<gl\GLU.h>
#include<gl\GL.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv){

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("Simple GLUT application");

    glutMainLoop();

}
```

Visual studio is not recognizing any of the glut methods and is throwing errors such as "glutInit not recognized"

I know it is some error with how I linked the libraries, but I am new at this, so please be kind. Anyone know how to get this example working properly?

Comment: how you setup glut in visual-studio? or not?

Answer (score 5):

You need to include the glut headers. Glut is the "GL utility toolkit" and is a separate library built on top of OpenGL, not part of OpenGL itself.

If you have them in the same directory as your other includes, it would read

```
#include<gl\GLUT.h>
```

For more info: [here](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/opengl/basics-of-glut-r1680)

Comment: You may want to use [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) instead though. It has almost exactly the same API as GLUT so you can use it interchangeably, but is better maintained.

Comment: And if you include `glut.h`, you don't need to include `gl.h` or `glu.h`

Answer (score -1):

Did you make sure that you copied glut32.dll to %windir%\system and glut.h to %VSdir%\VC\include\GL and glut32.lib to %VSdir%\lib? If you did it right then you shall see the Open GL methods in the intellisense.

Comment: -1:For the suggestion to add them into system directories. You should not be throwing things into system directories.